# Ubuntu 10.04 RGBA(Transparent theme) bug

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, desktop, themes

I tried to follow this tutorial frome ghacks.net. But I end up with a bug. Everytime I try to change the desktop background or the theme. It opens up lots of folders. And then close it back again. So I cannot do anything when I try to change the background or the theme to the default.
[Here is the tutorial](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/12/enable-rgba-support-in-ubuntu/)

And I can't even shutdown my machine now, please help.

**EDIT**
I tried executing these commands in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:erik-b-andersen/rgba-gtk
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-chooser gtk2-module-rgba
sudo apt-get install murrine-themes
```

And it installed gnome color changer. 
It works, and the windows became transparent, but I can't change to the default theme and I can't put a background

Here's the screenshot, when I try to change something in the preferences:
[Screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/Screenshot.png)

Its just okay if I can't change the theme, but it won't let me change the background either. Or maybe the background is changed but its transparent just like the other windows.
You can see that in the taskbar(or whatever its called in Ubuntu). Its full.
What can I do to atleast make the background visible.

Comment: tutorial link broken.  please explain what you tried; as-is this is not answerable.

Comment: the link is fixed. Check out the edit

Comment: Are you using the appearance properties to change your background, or something else?

Comment: yup, see the edit. See what actually happens when I try to change background or theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment thread in that tutorial, try updating Nautilus again.